# Refresh window form

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I have two WinForms:

*admin.cs* which is a Windows.Forms.Form

*addManager.cs* which is a Windows.Forms.UserControl

***addManager*** userControl is inside the Form ***admin.cs***

---

In ***admin.cs*** I have a refresh button, and here's the code of it:

```
   if (admin.ActiveForm != null)
   {
       this.Dispose();
       admin NewForm = new admin();
       NewForm.Show();
   }
```

Now, I decided to get rid of the refresh button on ***admin.cs***, and move the code of it to the another button in ***addManager.cs***

```
***addManager.cs***

private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ...
     if (admin.ActiveForm != null)
     {
         this.Dispose();
         admin NewForm = new admin();
         NewForm.Show();
     }
}
```

The program has no errors, but the current form is not closing, instead the *NewForm* is appearing making it two Windows at the same time. The left window is the old window I want to dispose upon showing of the ***NewForm*** (right window)
[*photo for reference*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfmli.png)

What I want to do is to automatically refresh the form through button in different form (userControl).

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this in the button click event. First hide the current form and close it in the Closed event.

```
this.Hide();
admin newForm = new admin();
newForm.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close(); 
newForm.Show();
```

Comment: I still get the same output. It still shows the current form. What I do is I paste your answer in button click event in **admin.cs** and from **addManager.cs** what i do is to perform click like this 

`admin newForm = new admin();                         newForm.btnRefresh.PerformClick(); `